# Relationships between diagonals in a right kite

Tags: geometry

In a right kite, the segments extending from the intersection of the diagonals to the vertices in clockwise order to be $d_{1}$, $d_{2}$, $d_{3}$, and $d_{4}$, then,

$$d_{1}d_{3}=d_{2}d_{4}$$

This is a handy relationship to know with respect to these shapes.

Is there any other way to relate the length of the diagonals, especially without the use of square roots or trig functions? For example, if the lengths of $BD$ and $k$ are known, what is the length of $AC$?

[image]

Comment: FYI: The product relation isn't specific to right-kites, but applies to any [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral). (A right-kite is such, because the right angles imply that the long diagonal is a diameter of a circumcircle.) The equal products $d_1d_3$ and $d_2d_4$ give a value known as the "power" of the intersection pt with respect to the circumcircle; the same value results as the product of the parts of *any* chord of the circumcircle passing through that pt. (See Wikipedia's ["Power of a Point" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point).)

Comment: Write the area of the kite with the sides and the diagonals - than no need of square roots